# Count of rows month wise for a given year

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select Registration per month.

```
<?php
include 'member_entry/sdg_connect.php';

$sql="select member_id from sdg_members where member_joindate BETWEEN  DATE('2015-02-30') AND DATE( '2016-12-31')";

if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
      $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
      echo $rowcount;

      mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you want result for all months or specific month?

Comment: `2015-02-30` 30 February 2015 ???

Comment: for specific months per year

Comment: Then have a look @ScaisEdge's answer.

Comment: Note that date() is redundant here. And don't include comments like 'asap' on SO. Your question is no more worthy our attention than any other.

Comment: we are still waiting for your response... did u checked other answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As scaisEdge already mentioned, you have to use `group by`:

```
select
  YEAR(member_joindate) AS year, MONTH(member_joindate) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) AS joins
from
  sdg_members
where
  member_joindate BETWEEN '2015-02-30' AND '2016-12-31'
group by
  YEAR(member_joindate), MONTH(member_joindate)
```

This will give you results in the form of

```
year | month | joins
2015 |     3 |    10
2015 |     4 |     3
2015 |     5 |    11
...
```

Afterwards you do not need to apply `num_rows` anymore, you just have to go through the result set

Comment: what shold i be using to echo / print the output/result

Comment: this is basic studd, you should know:
Something like this:
`$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
echo $row['month'] . ". " . $row['year'] . ": " . $row['joins'];
}`

Comment: This is know it provides me all the rows. But i wanted to show one row with a variable, so that i can use it as bar graph value

Answer (score 3):

You can use an aggregate function count() and group by it by month

```
$sql="select count(member_id), month(member_joindate) 
from sdg_members
where member_joindate BETWEEN  str_to_date('30/02/2015', '%d/%m/%Y')
    AND    str_to_date('31/12/2016', '%d/%m/%Y')  
group by month(member_joindate) ";
```

Comment: > it just given me 0 as the output

Comment: i am getting `0` as the output

Comment: there isn't any date conversion

Comment: @PrakashLal: if its not date conversion, than us simple: SELECT COUNT(member_id), MONTH(member_joindate) 
from sdg_members
where member_joindate BETWEEN '2015-02-30' AND '2016-12-31'   
group by MONTH(member_joindate)

Answer (score 0):

If datatype of `member_joindate` column is just `DATE` than you can use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(member_id), MONTH(member_joindate) 
from sdg_members
where member_joindate BETWEEN '2015-02-30' AND '2016-12-31'   
group by MONTH(member_joindate)
```

If datatype of `member_joindate` column is just `DATETIME` than you can use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(member_id), MONTH(member_joindate) 
from sdg_members
where member_joindate BETWEEN '2015-02-30 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 23:59:59'   
group by MONTH(member_joindate)
```

Keep in mind `MONTH()` will return the month number, you can also use `MONTHNAME()` function.

```
SELECT COUNT(sb_id), MONTHNAME(sb_ondate) 
from sbbleads_members
where sb_ondate BETWEEN '2015-02-30' AND '2016-12-31'   
group by MONTHNAME(sb_ondate);
```